# Dpkg broken pipe error when using os.popen in Python

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, gtk

I'm experimenting with Gtk+ 3 and I'm creating a program which gets the output of the `dpkg --get-selections` command and displays it into a Gtk+ 3 `TextView`.

When I run my program I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 36, in <module>
    window = dpkgApp()
  File "file1.py", line 24, in __init__
    with open("", "w") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
dpkg: error: error writing to '<standard output>': Broken pipe
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import io, subprocess, os
from gi.repository import Gtk

class dpkgApp(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Software/dependencies")

        self.table = Gtk.Table(3, 3, True)
        self.add(self.table)

        self.scrollWindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.table.attach(self.scrollWindow, 0, 1, 0, 1)

        self.textView = Gtk.TextView()
        self.scrollWindow.add(self.textView)

#######################################################################
        subprocess.call("dpkg --get-selections", shell=True)
        dpkg_output = os.popen("dpkg --get-selections")

        with open("", "w") as f:
            f.writeline(dpkg_output)
            f.close()

        buffer = Gtk.TextBuffer()
        self.textView.get_buffer(buffer)
        self.textView.set_editable(False)
        self.textView.set_wrap_mode(True)
        self.textView.set_cursor_visible(False)

        buffer.set_text(dpkg_output)

window = dpkgApp()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Looking on StackOverflow, it appears to be a problem with `subprocess`
, but I'm using the `os` module to get the `dpkg` command output - and the error ouput includes `dpkg: error:`, so maybe it's a `dpkg` error?

I've tried replacing the `os.popen` line with `os.Popen(["dpkg --get-selections"], stdout=PIPE)` and adding `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE` but I just get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dpkg --get-selections` call works alright; the problem is in the following line 24 where you try to open a file with empty file name:

```
with open("", "w") as f:
```

Empty file names are not allowed. Use a "real" file name, or a temporary file of you don't want to care about names and location:

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f:
```

Furthermore, `file` has no function `writeline`, you're probably looking for `writelines`.

```
f.writelines(dpkg_output)
```

Comment: it's not the open function - I've tried that... But I'll check anyway :)